# Drop down form attached to button

Tags: forms, button

I would like to attach a form to a button so when the button is pressed a from will drop down beneath it. How would I make something like this?

I haven't provided any code as I do not think any code is needed other then the code that gets posted by someone who is responding to my question however I can provided code if code is needed but I didn't think it was.

Thank you for reading this.

FORM CODE

```
<form action="team.php" method="POST" name="profiles">
<div>Team Name: <input type="text" name="team" value="<?php echo $cx;?>"></div>
<input type="submit" name="signupbtn">
</form>
```

Button Code

```
<button class="myButtont"><?php echo "<a href=esports/create/team.php>Create a Team</a>";?></button>
```

You might think why am I echoing out a link. This is because I will be including the team name from the database as a variable so please do not ask why I am echoing a link.

Comment: to the form and the button? I haven't tried to do it at all as I don't know where to start. I am adding to post now

Comment: @Shivam are you going to reply or was you just wasting my time?

Comment: sorry for late answer, I was busy somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code,

```
<div id="div1" style="visibility:hidden;">
    <form action="team.php" method="POST" name="profiles">
    <div>Team Name: <input type="text" name="team" value="<?php echo $cx;?>"></div>
    <input type="submit" name="signupbtn">
    </form>
</div>
```

Button Code,

```
<button class="myButtont" onclick='showForm();'><?php echo "<a href='#'>Create a Team</a>";?></button>
```

Use this script in your HTML file,

```
<script>
function showForm() { 
   document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility= 'visible' ;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you very much. I was thinking that you made me post the code for laughs. Thanks once again :)

Comment: Your code works like a dream however when the form is hidden it creates a gap where the form is. Is there a way so basically the button stores the form until it has been clicked so there is no gap where the form is hiding

Answer (score 1):

You can use popup window to display the form. You have to use the button as anchor view from where it has to drop down. More you can find http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Comment: Is there not a way to have it drop down beneath the button itself? Thank you for your comment as I will use this if I can not gt the from to drop down beneath the button

Comment: mmm I see your link i for android. Is that not just for mobile use?